# DISEÑO RESPONSIVE - NAVBAR

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Mi problema es el siguiente (screenshot)

[image]

Quiero que el formulario de búsqueda aparezca al lado del botón del navbar.
en diseño web aparece bien, el problema es cuando lo abro desde el móvil
adjunto código:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" id="MenuNav">

      <!--    BOTON DEL NAVBAR -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <!------------------------------>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <!-- CONTENIDO DEL NAV -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- FORM DE BUSQUEDA  -->
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ej: SmarTv" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" id="button-addon2">Buscar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!------------------------>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Y si publicas tu codigo an algun sitio como https://codepen.io/ ?

Comment: En móvil se ve como tu quieres,. de hecho editaron tu pregunta agregando los link de las librerías y si das en ejecutar podrás ver lo que te comento. Si no, no en tiendo cual es tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

para evitar que el formulario de busqueda salte a la siguiente linea debes añadir a el `navbar` la clase `flex-nowrap` (que evita los saltos de linea) y `align-items-baseline` (para centrar los elementos).

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white flex-nowrap align-items-baseline" id="MenuNav">

      <!--    BOTON DEL NAVBAR -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <!------------------------------>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <!-- CONTENIDO DEL NAV -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- FORM DE BUSQUEDA  -->
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ej: SmarTv" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" id="button-addon2">Buscar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!------------------------>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```